# Can you compare Propensity Score Matching estimates?

Tags: regression, econometrics, propensity-scores, research-design

I am considering a research project involving Propensity Score Matching (PSM). For a high-level overview, I am looking at college students. Colleges offer need-based, and merit-based scholarships. I am attempting to test whether there is a differential impact on students' grades and college persistence based on the framing of the scholarship they receive (i.e., need-based vs merit-based). So, if I were to construct 2 independent PSM models (1 for need-based vs. control and another for merit-based vs control), would I be able to compare the estimations? I.e., would I be able to say framing scholarships as need-based would have a stronger positive impact on grades than framing them as merit-based (or vice versa depending on results)?

Answer (score 4):

I am not positive, but I think you could do this from a purely statistical perspective. The difference between getting and not getting a scholarship will be estimated for each equation and those two estimates can be compared.

But I think that the comparison may have some flaws. Presumably, a lot of merit-based scholarship winners (not all, but a lot) are going to get high grades anyway. After all, some merit scholarships are awarded, in part, based on grades, SAT scores, and so on. So, even the merit based student who do not get scholarships may get high grades. There would be ceiling effects.

Of course, some need based students, even without the scholarship, may get high grades, but I am pretty sure it would be a far lower percentage.

Answer (score 4):

Propensity score matching is an inefficient way to adjust for confounding.  It is not needed unless the number of potential confounders is so large that you can’t model them as individual covariates.  PS matching like PS weighting results in a marginal effect estimate, and this estimate is a function of the particular distribution of confounders in your sample.  If the sample covariate distributions do not match the target inference population distributions you may get a marginal estimate that may not apply.  This is especially true when a linear model is not being used.

Answer (score 2):

First, if your research question is about comparing two groups, why are you including a third group (controls) at all? Second, why don't you use a method specifically designed for comparing multiple groups? There are matching and weighting methods specifically designed for such comparisons. The key to using them and ensuring validity of the comparisons is to ensure they target a meaningful population and that each comparison targets the same population. For example, with matching, if you select the control groups as the focal group and find merit-based students similar to the controls and need-based students similar to the controls, you would be estimating the average treatment effect on the controls, i.e., the effects of receiving a scholarship for those that didn't. Treated each scholarship group as focal and doing two separate matches (finding controls similar to the merit-based and, separately, finding controls similar to need-based) would yield matched samples that correspond to different target populations and therefore would be incomparable to each other (i.e., any difference you could be due to the composition of the samples, not the type of scholarship. Finally, you would need to restrict your target population a lot to ensure overlap is met; need-based and merit-based students will likely look extremely different from each other; it is unlikely you will find a student who could have gone one way or another, and if you do find such a student, they will be a very unusual type of student and the effect might not generalize to other students.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I think my issue comes from the fact that I dont know what those scoring and/or weighting methods are called, so I haven’t gotten the chance to research them. You mention ignoring the control - could we do a PSM with just need based vs. merit based? Also, if we were to limit the sample to only high achieving & low-income students could we then proceed with my method of 2 separate PSMs?

Comment: If your goal is to compare need-based vs merit-based, it's unclear to me why you thought to include control units in the first place. Perhaps you can clarify that. You don't need to artificially limit your sample; the matching will do that automatically. The point is that the sample you end up with may not be very informative; it may be a very small sample of just those with high need and high merit, who are vastly unlike other students, if there are any such students at all (and you are assuming that such students may in fact receive either type almost at random).

Comment: My understanding was that PSM only works when comparing a Treatment and Control, and I wasn’t sure I could treat a student who receives need based aid as a control subject and a merit based aid receiver as a treatment subject. I think it still would be informative to find what framing of scholarship is best for students who do fall into that high need high merit bucket. When you say we assume they receive it at random, I’m a little confused - isnt the point that they don’t receive it at random, and we are using PSM to mimic random assignment?

Comment: PSM doesn't know what labels you are using for your two treatment groups; it is a statistical method used to compare two groups. It is often used in comparative effectiveness research, i.e., when two active treatments are being compared. The only reason "treated" and "control" are used in PSM tutorials is because these are simple labels that evoke a randomized experiment.